Can I stay in the USA for two weeks on a Green Card every six months?
I am a green cardholder. I work in the USA and pay taxes to the US government. My property and driving license are from the USA. Due to my family situation, I must travel outside the USA and care for them every week. I am not interested in Citizenship, but can I enter the United States every six months for two weeks to maintain my green card status? My intention is not to scam the system, but I need to travel due to my family situation. I need to do this for another few years.
